# jQuery class selector and text adding

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementsbyclassname

I have two files `index.html` and `star.js`.
My index file looks so:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="foo">
            <h2>First:</h2>
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="foo">
            <h2>Second:</h2>
            <p>5</p>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="star.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </html>
```

And my js file looks like that:

```js
    var element = $(".foo > p");
    //Try to figure it out
    console.log('First: ' + element.text() + ' second: ' + element.text());
```

All I want from this code is just log out in the right sequence:

```
First: 3 second: 5
```

But my console gives me this:

```
First: 35 second: 35
```

I know that `$(".%classname%)` method looks thought all `foo` classes in the file but it doesn't return an array. Can I solve my problem somehow?

1. I need to use jQuery. Not pure js with .getElementsByClassName.
2. I can't change my classes name. .foo requires.
3. I need the solution which doesn't depend on number of classes.

The nearest solution I found in :eq() pseudo-selector but is there any other ways?

Comment: Is it only these two elements or are there more elements?

Comment: If you want to return an array you can use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) - `element.map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();`

Comment: I've upd my question. It could be any number of elements with .foo class

Comment: @billyonecan it's a very narrow solution because it depends upon index. in my question I want to put random text before each `p` value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text method will return text contents of all the elements present in the jQuery object.

You will have to iterate over the items in the elements then print each one like

```js
var element = $(".foo");
element.each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  snippet.log($this.find('h2').text() + ': ' + $this.find('p').text());
})
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <h2>First:</h2>
  <p>3</p>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <h2>Second:</h2>
  <p>5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It almost looks like what I want. But if I want to print differ text from `<h2>` value like: `1: 3 and 2: 5`

Comment: Thanks but is there the universal way where I can put any value before `p` like: `one: 3 and two: 5` without changing HTML file?

Comment: @VadZelenin how do you define the values to be put

Comment: @VadZelenin to display a predefined set of values - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3bnaocfk/3/

Comment: look there below in the comment after the second answer. Using array of sings it the best way. Thank you for your engaging.

Answer (score 0):

Try

$('.foo:nth-child(1) p').text()

and

$('.foo:nth-child(2) p').text()

**EDIT:** going to bring my answer out of fiddle for future reference:

Use a loop to iterate through *any number* of elements

```
for(i=1; i <= $('div.foo').length; i++){
        $('.output').append($('.foo:nth-child('+i+') h1').text() + ": ");
    $('.output').append($('.foo:nth-child('+i+') p').text() + "<br/>");
}
```

Comment: Good. But look at the note I've made in my question. There could be any number of elements with class `foo`.

Comment: Thank you. `.length` method solves it. But I can't pass any text I want instead of `h2` values.

Comment: You can pass any text you want if you wish it to be repeating. http://jsfiddle.net/cshanno/vrpeyvjw/2/.  There are only a few ways you get get unique output in place of the h2 value. You either have to use incrementing numbers, like Arun mentioned above with (i+1), replace the h2 value with what you will want to log, or (tedious) you could build an array with a length = number of elements you will log contents of, and inside the loop access your array with a counter ex(http://jsfiddle.net/cshanno/vrpeyvjw/3/).

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I want. Solution with array of signs for each number is a perfect solution.